# How to get Dynamic Span id in jquery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, html

Iam using jquery in asp.net

I have one user control in which i have div and in div table and in table tr and in tr td and in td i have lables.

ASCX :

```
          <div  ID="Container" runat="server" class="dvContainer">
<table ID="Table" class = "Tablecs">
    <thead><tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text="Swiss" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
        </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>DEF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblPA" Text="SUN 12/21 05:04" runat="server" /></td>
        <td ><asp:Label ID="lblPD" Text="SUN 12/21 19:00" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblAA" Text="SUN 12/21 05:04" runat="server" /></td>
        <td ><asp:Label ID="lblAD" Text="SUN 12/21 19:00" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i want to bind data dynamically to these user control. i.e., binding data to lables in user contol.

my Jquery

```
            $div.find(".Table").text(oPorts[iCount].Name); // my result is an array of oPorts and i have filed as Name
```

But this is not working fine.
when i checked into code dynamically its generating SPAN for each and every lable
How to find that SPAN id dynamiccaly in a loop and bind data to lables??

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you have any unique that's returned from DB, add it to the id attribute of your span.

Comment: But i dont have any span in my page should i create one span for any tr or td???

Comment: asp:labels get rendered to span. all your elements (including labels) inside the usercontrol are runat="server", that means their id is going to be modified at the runtime. when you run your page, goto the viewsource and look for the pattern of IDs being assigned to your lables i.e. spans, i.e. ucId_ctrl_lblPA_1, ucId_ctrl_lblPA_2, then you can loop through such ids

Comment: Can you explain me little bit clearer , what you are trying to achieve ? this will help me solve your problem.

Comment: @Manoj  Iam trying to bind data  from data base dynamically to user control which is having lables

Comment: @ManishMishra Yes you are correct. But i tried with those dynamic id's also ..., which it has generated but still my problem is not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a usercontrol with a markup like given below

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
 CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="DOTNET_FORMS.WebUserControl1" %>

<div id="Container" runat="server" class="dvContainer">
    <table id="Table" class="Tablecs">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPA" Text="SUN 12/21 05:04" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPD" Text="SUN 12/21 19:00" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and you have registered this usercontrol on your `.aspx` page like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="Test" Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" %>
```

and used it like this:

```
<UC:Test ID="uc1" runat="server" />
```

then, when you run your page, your elements get rendered something like

```
<div id="uc1_Container" class="dvContainer">
    <table id="Table" class="Tablecs">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="uc1_lblPA">SUN 12/21 05:04</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="uc1_lblPD">SUN 12/21 19:00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="uc1_lblAA">SUN 12/21 05:04</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="uc1_lblAD">SUN 12/21 19:00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

see how ids of your labels and other elements (elements with `runat="server"` attribute ) got changed i.e.

```
lblPA > uc1_lblPA
lblPD > uc1_lblPD

Container > uc1_Container
```

so, you have to look out for these changes, because only then you can grab these elements using jQuery, cause jQuery is a client side language, it executes, after the server side code (runat="server") has executed.

However, if you do not want to look out for modified id, you can do following

1. remove `runat="server"` attribute, and make sure your ids are unique, all of them
2. let the `runat="server"` attribute be their, place an attribute `clientidmode="static"` on all of your server side controls. and Ids wont change.
3. use ClientId i.e. in your jQuery selector, grab an element like this: `$('#"+'<%= lblPA.ClientID %>');`

now, since your IDs are unique, you don't need to find, directly grab the elements like this:

```
$('#lblPA').text();
```

or if you want to loop through all the tds of your table with class `Tablecs`, do this:

```
$('.Tablecs tr td').each(function(index, item){
             alert($(item).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot..., Thanks for your clean explanation..Thanks and this will help me alot